# Student Locker Problem (Requires alternation within array)

Tags: c, algorithm

I have to solve this:

> A school has 100 lockers and 100 students. Student 1 opens all lockers. Student 2 toggles every 2nd locker starting from the first. Student 3 toggles every 3rd locker, starting from the back (the 100th). This goes all the way to the Nth student. (They alternate, starting from the back or front).

I have to display the open lockers at the end. I can't seem to figure out how to make the alternating requirement work. Here's the code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_LOCKERS 100
#define MAX_STUDENTS 100

int main (void)
{
int i, n;
bool locker[MAX_LOCKERS + 1];

for ( i = 1; i <= 100; ++i )
    locker[i] = true;

for ( i = 2; i <= 100; ++i ) 
    for ( n = i; n <= 100; n += i )
        locker[n] = ! locker[n];
        if ( locker[i] )
            printf ("%i ", i);

printf ("\nThe open lockers are: ");

for ( i = 1; i <= 100; ++i )
    if ( locker[i] )
        printf ("%i ", i);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need braces around your loops. The first call to `printf` is superfluous. `++i` should be `i += 2`, with a second loop counting down. Does it matter what order students toggle the lockers in?

Comment: @LegendofPedro in the first loop, `i` represents the locker number, but in the second loop, the outer `i` is being used for the *student* number.

Comment: Okay, so how does the result differ from what you expect?

Comment: Toggling the lockers from different directions does affect the result. I think the result suppose to be 1, 2, 4, 8, 9..etc

Comment: The main thing here is that the direction they are toggled alternates as well.

Comment: If even students always go up from 1 and odd students go down from 100, I think the output is the same if they go in order `1, 2, 3, 4...` or `1, 3, 5 ... 2, 4, 6 ...`.

Comment: I wonder if anyone approaches this problem with bit shifting and Boolean algebra.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/B19EbNpYB   I think the correct answer is The open lockers are: 1 2 3 8 18 20 29 32 37 50 51 52 65 69 72 76 83 85 92 93 97 98 99 100

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_LOCKERS 100
#define MAX_STUDENTS 100
// You should use this preprocessor directive!

int main (void)
{
    int i, n;
    bool locker[MAX_LOCKERS + 1];

    for ( n = 1; n <= MAX_LOCKERS; ++n) // student 1
        locker[n] = true;
        // Be consistent with usage of i/n. Even better, use descriptive names!

    for ( i = 2; i <= MAX_STUDENTS; i+=2)  { // even students
        for ( n = 1; n <= MAX_LOCKERS; n += i ) {
            // 2nd student goes from 1st to 100th, not ith to 100th
            locker[n] = ! locker[n];
        }
    }
    // Multiplying by -1 (toggle) is distributive and associative so we can split these loops up
    for ( i = 3; i <= MAX_STUDENTS; i+=2)  { // odd students
        for ( n = MAX_LOCKERS; n >= 1; n -= i )
            locker[n] = ! locker[n];
    }

    printf ("\nThe open lockers are: ");
    for ( i = 1; i <= MAX_LOCKERS; ++i ) {
        if ( locker[i] )
            printf ("%i ", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I typed this on my phone<s>, so I haven't tested it</s>. To test my assumption about being able to split the loop into two, hand calculate both ways with 5 lockers/students. <s>(I'll edit to add output/a proof when it's not 0215 and I shouldn't be sleeping!)</s>

I have commented corrections/suggestions.

You could also use a single `while` loop, and determine adding or subtracting the iterator with `%`, the integer modulo operator.

---

Output:

```
The open lockers are: 2 3 9 28 33 36 50 64 68 73 75 82 84 91 92 96 98
```

Here's the example showing that the toggling operations can be performed in any order:
[image: lockers-sequence]

You can perform a more rigorous proof, if you like, but I thought it was fairly easy to intuit.

Comment: I'm not sure.  The way I read it the question says "Student 2 toggles every 2nd locker starting from the first" which means they ignore locker 1 and toggle locker 2 then 4, etc.  And the same with "Student 3 toggles every 3rd locker, starting from the back (the 100th)." which means they don't toggle 100 or 99 but toggles the third one he comes to: 98.  Also, maybe I am missing something, but where does your code do Student 4 through 100?

Comment: It would be clearer with `MAX_LOCKERS` and `MAX_STUDENTS`. `for(i=2:2:100) for(n=1:i:100)` has the even ith students (2,4,...100) toggle the ith locker.

Comment: "Student 2 toggles every 2nd locker starting from the first." I.e. locker 1. "Student 3 toggles every 3rd locker, starting from the back (the 100th)." Seems clear to me, maybe I am reading it "starts at the back" though? Student 1 doesn't ignore the 1st locker.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you read it.  If someone said to me "open every second locker starting from this end" I wouldn't open the first locker.  And if they said "Open every third locker starting from the back"  I wouldn't open the last locker.  But I can see how you could read it that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem that should hinge on *odd/even* in determining whether to work from the *beginning to end* or from the *end to beginning* toggling locker doors through all students.

Where you will horribly confuse yourself is mixing *element numbers* (e.g. `for ( i = 1; i <= 100; ++i )`) with *array indexes* (e.g. `for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)`). It is always best to keep in mind that arrays are ***zero indexed*** in C and be consistent in your loop limits loop `0 -> n-1` instead of `1 -> n`

(**note:** both are of course legal, but using the actual index eliminates the potential for violating your array bounds with an **off-by-one** for failure to adjust your indexes when looping `1 -> n`)

(**edit-note:** I was off-by-one on the loop increment -- fixed)

The basic approach after setting all lockers open is to loop with the actual remaining student *indexes*, looping `1 -> n-1`. If the current student is **odd** then work from the beginning to end toggling lockers. If the current student is **even** compute the last index that can be reached with multiples of the current value (e.g. `end = (100 / current) * current)` with integer division intentional. (you may need `end = 100 - (current+1);` depending on if you want to start 3rd from the end with student 3, etc...)  Now loop from `end` while greater or equal to zero toggling lockers.

It may help simplify things if you write a simple toggle locker function, e.g.

```
void toggle (int *locker, int idx)
{
    if (locker[idx])        /* if locker open */
        locker[idx] = 0;    /* close it */
    else                    /* otherwise */
        locker[idx] = 1;    /* open it */
}
```

Then you avoid duplicating the conditionals in main logic of your code. Your code uses `bool`, which is fine, but I generally simply use `int` instead. So for your main logic, you could use something similar to:

```
    int i, j;
    int locker[MAX_LOCKERS + 1];

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)                   /* open all lockers */
        locker[i] = 1;

    for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {                 /* loop all other students */
        if (i % 2 == 1)                         /* odd, from start */
            for (j = i; j < 100; j += (i+1))    /* loop j=i , j += (i+1) */
                toggle (locker, j);             /* toggle lockers at j */
        else {                                  /* if even index */
            int end = (100 / i) * i;            /* get end index by i */
            for (j = end; j >= 0; j -= (i+1))   /* from end, loop j -= (i+1) */
                toggle (locker, j);             /* toggle lockers at j */
        }
    }
```

Putting it altogether, (and leaving it to you to substitute `MAX_STUDENTS` for your use of `100` in your code), you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LOCKERS 100
#define MAX_STUDENTS 100

void toggle (int *locker, int idx)
{
    if (locker[idx])        /* if locker open */
        locker[idx] = 0;    /* close it */
    else                    /* otherwise */
        locker[idx] = 1;    /* open it */
}

int main (void)
{
    int i, j;
    int locker[MAX_LOCKERS + 1];

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)                   /* open all lockers */
        locker[i] = 1;

    for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {                 /* loop all other students */
        if (i % 2 == 1)                         /* odd, from start */
            for (j = i; j < 100; j += (i+1))    /* loop j=i , j += (i+1) */
                toggle (locker, j);             /* toggle lockers at j */
        else {                                  /* if even index */
            int end = (100 / i) * i;            /* get end index by i */
            for (j = end; j >= 0; j -= (i+1))   /* from end, loop j -= (i+1) */
                toggle (locker, j);             /* toggle lockers at j */
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {     /* output results in grid form */
        if (i && i % 10 == 0)
            putchar ('\n');
        printf (" %s", locker[i] ? "[x]" : "[ ]");
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Outputting the final state of the lockers in grid form, (you can do it however you like)

```
$ ../bin/openlockers2
 [ ] [ ] [x] [x] [ ] [ ] [ ] [x] [ ] [x]
 [x] [ ] [x] [ ] [ ] [x] [x] [ ] [ ] [ ]
 [ ] [ ] [ ] [x] [x] [x] [x] [x] [ ] [x]
 [x] [ ] [x] [x] [x] [x] [x] [ ] [ ] [ ]
 [ ] [ ] [x] [x] [ ] [x] [x] [x] [x] [ ]
 [ ] [x] [ ] [ ] [x] [ ] [x] [ ] [ ] [ ]
 [ ] [x] [x] [ ] [x] [x] [ ] [x] [x] [ ]
 [x] [ ] [x] [ ] [ ] [x] [ ] [x] [x] [ ]
 [ ] [x] [ ] [x] [ ] [x] [ ] [ ] [x] [x]
 [x] [ ] [x] [x] [x] [ ] [x] [x] [x] [x]
```

`[x]` - locker open. (you may want to swap that if it makes more sense to you)

**NOTE:** This is intended to show an approach to handle your students working forward or backwards through the remaining number of students. **I have not spent time verifying the logic is correct...** I suspect it is (or is very close), but the final validation of the correctness is left to you.

If using the alternate definition of `end` to, e.g. start toggling 3rd from end with the 3rd student, you would have:

```
            int end = 100 - (i+1);
            for (j = end; j >= 0; j -= (i+1))   /* from end, loop j -= (i+1) */
                toggle (locker, j);             /* toggle lockers at j */
```

and consequently:

```
$ ./bin/openlockers2
 [x] [x] [x] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [x] [ ] [ ]
 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [x] [ ] [x]
 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [x] [ ]
 [ ] [x] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [x] [ ] [ ] [ ]
 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [x]
 [x] [x] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
 [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [x] [ ] [ ] [ ] [x] [ ]
 [ ] [x] [ ] [ ] [ ] [x] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
 [ ] [ ] [x] [ ] [x] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
 [ ] [x] [x] [ ] [ ] [ ] [x] [x] [x] [x]
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.